# Ordering the results by the range key in DynamoDB does not work

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table definition like the following:

```
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = 'AttributeName', 'AttributeType'
    my_table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='my_table',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            ATTRIBUTE_NAME: 'order_id',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'
        },
        {
            ATTRIBUTE_NAME: 'time',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            ATTRIBUTE_NAME: 'order_id',
            ATTRIBUTE_TYPE: 'S'
        },
        {
            ATTRIBUTE_NAME: 'time',
            ATTRIBUTE_TYPE: 'S'
        },
        {
            ATTRIBUTE_NAME: 'market_product',
            ATTRIBUTE_TYPE: 'S'
        }
    ],
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes=[
        {
            'IndexName': 'market_product_index',
            'KeySchema': [
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'market_product',
                    'KeyType': 'HASH'
                },
            ],
            'Projection': {
                'ProjectionType': 'KEYS_ONLY'
            },
            'ProvisionedThroughput': {
                'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
                'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
            }
        }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
    }
    )
```

Here I create dummy data for this table:

```
from uuid import uuid4 as uuid

my_table_dummy = [
    {
        'order_id': str(uuid()),
        'time': '2019-02-13 15:07:55.575960',
        'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
        'side': 'buy',
        'size': '10.2',
        'weighted_price': '21.3'
    },
    {
        'order_id': str(uuid()),
        'time': '2019-02-13 15:06:55.575960',
        'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
        'side': 'buy',
        'size': '10.2',
        'weighted_price': '21.3'
    },
    {
        'order_id': str(uuid()),
        'time': '2019-02-12 15:06:55.575960',
        'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
        'side': 'buy',
        'size': '10.2',
        'weighted_price': '21.3'
    },
    {
        'order_id': str(uuid()),
        'time': '2019-02-12 15:06:55.575961',
        'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
        'side': 'buy',
        'size': '10.2',
        'weighted_price': '21.3'
    },
    {
        'order_id': str(uuid()),
        'time': '2019-02-11 15:06:55.575960',
        'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
        'side': 'buy',
        'size': '10.2',
        'weighted_price': '21.3'
    }
]

for dummy_sample in my_table_dummy:
    my_table.put_item(Item=dummy_sample)
```

I read that when one queries the above and uses `ScanForwardIndex` flag, then, the results are sorted by the range key, which in this case is `time`. However, I am not getting the intended behaviour of obtaining the results of the query in descending/ascending order by `time` attribute:

```
response = my_table.query(
    IndexName='market_product_index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('market_product').eq('bitmex:BTC-USD'),
    ScanIndexForward=True
)
```

and response looks like this, i.e. not ordered by time at all:

```
{'Items': [{'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
   'order_id': '0d9fd701-5a7e-4348-bb01-631388c2c246',
   'time': '2019-02-12 15:06:55.575960'},
  {'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
   'order_id': '8cc1f2a2-0bc5-4169-aca5-cf37abbb5bc4',
   'time': '2019-02-11 15:06:55.575960'},
  {'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
   'order_id': 'd23cfa2c-9ae6-403b-ae57-1e1a3796e116',
   'time': '2019-02-13 15:06:55.575960'},
  {'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
   'order_id': '29095ee3-588f-4fb8-98a0-ce34adf028ea',
   'time': '2019-02-12 15:06:55.575961'},
  {'market_product': 'bitmex:BTC-USD',
   'order_id': '6cacd8fa-a2d0-4f2d-8041-a30fa5252c3b',
   'time': '2019-02-13 15:07:55.575960'}],
 'Count': 5,
 'ScannedCount': 5,
 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'bbc8bc0e-218a-4669-ba52-4ac07cc7bb60',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
   'x-amz-crc32': '365619475',
   'x-amzn-requestid': 'bbc8bc0e-218a-4669-ba52-4ac07cc7bb60',
   'content-length': '738',
   'server': 'Jetty(8.1.12.v20130726)'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are returned in no particular order because your index doesn’t have a sort key. Indexes do not automatically inherit any structure from the base table.

By choosing keys only, you are telling DynamoDB that the primary key of the table should be projected to the GSI, but DynamoDB will not assume that you want your GSI to be sorted by the same attribute.

You can fix this by deleting and recreating your GSI with time stamp as the GSI sort key.

Comment: thanks. Would this cause any issues with duplication? Would it understand that I am referring to the same time attribute from the KeySchema?

Comment: There should be no issues at all with doing this. DynamoDB doesn’t care whether or not it’s the same attribute—you just tell it what attribute you want to be the sort key, and it will sort on that attribute.